# how to install mono 2.10.8 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mono, ubuntu-18.04

Is there a way to download/install mono runtime 2.10.8.3 on Ubuntu 18.04?

I'm trying to run an app that requires this particular version. I don't have the source code for the app to rebuild it with a newer version of mono.

The only version of mono that I see available in the default repository is 4.6.2.7.

I appreciate all suggestions you may have.
Thank you.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to turn back time.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are older versions available, but not always.

You can try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version

If that does not work you have to find a repository that has an older version available. You can find more [info here](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#accessing-older-releases).

Although it is not recommended to revert to older versions because of security reason, so keep that in mind.